# When mapping using a custom XSLT file, changes work when testing locally but fail when deployed to the server

Tags: xslt, biztalk

I have a map in BizTalk 2010 that uses a [Custom XSLT Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560154.aspx) file.

When I have made changes to the transformation in the .xsl file in Visual Studio, I test the map file using the built-in tools (right-click the .btm file and choose **Test Map**).

This all works as expected and produces the required output file in Visual Studio.

However when deploying the assembly to BizTalk, I find that none of my transformation changes are reflected.  No amount of restarting host instances, terminating active instances, etc. solves the problem.

Why don't my changes make it into BizTalk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Agreed that this is an annoyance in Visual Studio.

What works best for me is to 'show all files' on the maps project so that the `.btm.cs` files are visible, and then to delete those `.btm.cs` files associated with maps which have changed. Rebuilding will then force VS to regenerate the `.btm.cs` file and pull the new xslt through.

Comment: +1 This is probably less hassle than deleting the reference to the XSLT as you don't even need to open the .btm file.

Comment: This answer was crucial in solving my problem. In my case though, this led us to discovering that even when entering a relative path here, the designer appears to resolve the path immediately (based apparently on C:\Windows\System32), and then calculate the relative path to that resolved absolute path based on the location of devenv.exe...all of which is totally insane. In the end we had to manually edit the .btm file to insert our relative path, which works at compile time, but this is another case hinting that BizTalk has never been used in a source controlled environment, ever.

Answer (score 1):

The BizTalk map file itself (.btm) is what gets compiled.  When changing the transformation, only the .xsl file actually gets edited, so Visual Studio doesn't realise that the assembly needs to be recompiled.

To resolve the problem, you need to ensure that the .btm file is also edited.  This will force the whole lot to be recompiled.

In **BizTalk 2009**, simply opening the .btm file and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save the map seemed to do the trick, as it would update a timestamp in the file's underlying XML.

However in **BizTalk 2010** this doesn't appear to work as the timestamp is no longer present.  It would seem the simplest way to force a recompile is to remove the reference to the custom .xsl file and then add it back in again, as suggested in the comments on [this blog](http://www.modhul.com/2007/06/08/xslt-map-changes-to-not-appear-when-re-deploying-biztalk-projects/).

There is also a suggestion that performing a **Rebuild** will do the trick, but I haven't personally had any success with that method.

Answer (score 0):

In BizTalk 2010 you can simply repaste the path to the XSLT you want to use in the Custom XSLT Path in the map Properties window.  This seems to count as a touch even if you are using the same file as before.